# Shopware 6: How to inject an entity repository using autowiring

Tags: symfony, autowired, shopware6

The "classical" way to inject an entity repository with Shopware 6 via the services.xml is like

```php
# your service/controller
private EntityRepository $productRepository;
...
public function __construct(
   EntityRepository $productRepository
) {
   $this->$productRepository = $productRepository;
}
...
```

```xml
<!-- your services.xml -->
<service id="...">
  <argument type="service" id="product.repository"/>
</service>
```

Now if I want to use Symfony's autowiring - what would be the equivalent to the above notation?

(In other words, my point here is how to tell Symfony I want the product.repository service to be wired, and not just the generic EntityRepository?)

Comment: You only need to make a service definition if the service container cannot scan the class. With [automatic service loading](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#service-container-services-load-example), you only have to define the classes in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found is in fact rather simple and straightforward :-) specify your constructor using the Autowire parameter attribute like this:

```php
    private readonly EntityRepository $productRepository;
    ...
    public function __construct(
        #[Autowire(service: 'product.repository')] EntityRepository $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }
```

If you adhere to Shopware's naming conventions, you may even omit the Autowire paramater, in the above example, the variable name `$productRepository` will be correctly resolved to the `'product.repository'` service. (Courtesy [@Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288568/alex)' comment see below)

Comment: Spoiler: It's not even necessary.. Shopware / Symfony knows from the variable name `$productRepository` what to inject!

Comment: A good hint, thx! I shall update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

A quick explanation how it works internally, so you better understand.

Shopware firstly finds definitions and then creates repositories dynamically during `CompilerPass` process.

https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/v6.5.5.1/src/Core/Framework/DependencyInjection/CompilerPass/EntityCompilerPass.php#L35

In the container (`aliasDefinitions` attribute) it ends up like:

```
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $aclRoleRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $aclUserRoleRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $appActionButtonRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $appActionButtonTranslationRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $appCmsBlockRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $appCmsBlockTranslationRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $appFlowActionRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $appFlowActionTranslationRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $appFlowEventRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $appPaymentMethodRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $appRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $appScriptConditionRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $appScriptConditionTranslationReposito = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $appTemplateRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $appTranslationRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $customFieldRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $customFieldSetRelationRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $customFieldSetRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $languageRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $logEntryRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $pluginRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $pluginTranslationRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $scheduledTaskRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $scriptRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $seoUrlRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $seoUrlTemplateRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $versionCommitDataRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $versionCommitRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias} 
Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository $versionRepository = {Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias}

[.....]
[.....]
[.....]
[.....]
```

So, in other words, usually you have those definitions:

```
MySampleDefinition.php
HelloWorldDefinition.php
MyCustomEntityDefinition.php
```

You will be able to access repositories like that automatically on your PHP files:

```
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository;

public function __construct(
    private EntityRepository $mySampleRepository,
    private EntityRepository $helloWorldRepository,
    private EntityRepository $myCustomEntityRepository,
) {
    
}
```

No worries about defining repositories by hand... however, you have to keep the pattern like`EntityRepository $myCustomEntityRepository`, otherwise you must explicitly pass it via `services.xml`